# What systems exhibit phase velocity close to group velocity

Tags: waves

I'm looking for physical examples of systems which support wavepackets, where the phase speed can be made (very) close to the phase velocity.

I know already that this happens in some optical guides and capillary waves, but do you have other physical examples ?

Comment: Sound, light. I probably do not understand the question.